# Google Drive Integration in AEM

Tags: aem

I want to integrate google drive in aem and want to fetch all photos of a folder exist in my google drive in my aem.
I used cloud services and i am able to fetch pageToken using auth 2.
Now i want to fetch the list of all files in that folder in the form of json using rest api. can someone advice me,how can i achieve it ?

```
  public JSONObject ImagesJson(String accessToken) throws IOException,JSONException {


    String url = "https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/{folder-id}/children?key={server-key}";
    String str = getHttpResponse(url, accessToken);
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(str);
    return jsonObject;
}

public static String getHttpResponse(String url, String accessToken) throws IOException {
    HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    InputStream is=null;
    if (url != null && url.trim().length() > 0) {

        try {
            URL _url = new URL(url);
            urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) _url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
            int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("Response Code  -- -- -- -- -- --  " + responseCode);
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            return response.toString();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if (urlConnection instanceof HttpURLConnection) {
                HttpURLConnection httpConn = urlConnection;
                int statusCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
                if (statusCode != 200) {
                    is = httpConn.getErrorStream();
                }
            }
            return e.getMessage();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I am taking the help of this code but response is coming as 400.Please help.

Comment: are you sure you are hitting the correct url with correct params? try getting the desired result by hitting the url from a web browser or curl, then implement it in java.

Comment: Yes i am sure i am done with the task.Will share you the complete ans here only very soon.